# Property on invisible control is still being bound to

Tags: c#

I have a simple radio button list inside a form view:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Answer") %>' Visible="false">
<asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="true" ></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="false"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

The "Answer" property does not exists, and even though RadioButtonList1 is invisible, it's still being bound to. Why is this? I've tried changing the visibility in various page life-cycle events with no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visibility has nothing to do with binding. You would have to remove either the binded property or the button itself for the binding to disappear.